# SaveFileDialog check free space before closing window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am trying to figure out how to effectively prevent saving data if there is not enought space to save.

Is it possible not to close the SaveFileDialog window and to show a message to user?

Comment: It would make more sense to check the free space of the drive after the SaveFileDialog is closed, then show a message. The reason being, you know where they are trying to save it (assuming its your SaveFileDialog)

Comment: you can always wrap the dialog with your own class and implement this functionality: checking the space, not closing when pressed ok, messaging why this did not work and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are trying to achive. The only difference to your request is that you will not check while the dialog is open but after the file is actually selected. Feel free to adapt this code to your need

```
    //Call this function instead of SaveFileDialog.Show()
    void showSaveDialog()
    {
        //Open dialog
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.ShowDialog();
        //check if file exists
        if (!File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
        {
            return;
        }
        // get the harddrive the user is saving on and get the free space
        string drive = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(sfd.FileName);
        double freeSpace = getFreeSpace(drive);
        double filesize = new System.IO.FileInfo(sfd.FileName).Length;

        //Messagebox if the is not enought space and restart
        if (  filesize > freeSpace)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Not enough free space on harddrive {drive}...\nFree space was {freeSpace} and file was {filesize}","Storage Error");
            showSaveDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            //save your file here
        }

    }

    double getFreeSpace(string drive)
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.Name==drive)
            {
                return d.AvailableFreeSpace;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: Very strange. A person who proposed this method have got 3 upvotes, but you implemented it and have no upvotes at all